# Father forces three kids to be in a pop band

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw a scene from this movie on VH1 yesterday (Saturday October 1) around 10:15 pm.

A father (could be in his 30s to 50s) wearing dark glasses (could have been sunglasses or just darkly tinted) was looking at his three kids in a music room in their house.  How do I know it was a music room?  There was a microphone, a guitar, some drums, and possibly other equipment.  The kids were squabbling over who would do what.  Everyone in the scene was Caucasian and speaking American English.  The kids all looked around 11 or 12 to me, just barely not teenagers.  For some reason I felt like the movie was set in the 70s or so, from the way people were dressed, although I don't have any specific details.

There were two girls and a boy.  One girl with longish dark hair got to be the singer (microphone).  When she was singing she sounded really professional, but I half-thought the microphone had some capability like autotune.  The boy (who seemed like the youngest) got to play the guitar.  Finally they asked "who will play the drums?" and the father tried to convince the other girl (who had maybe shorter brown hair?) to do it.  She kept saying "have you ever heard of a woman drummer?  No!" but she did go over and sit at the drums.

They all half-heartedly played a song together for a couple of lines (I don't remember which, but it was a well-known classic pop song) and then stopped.  The dad came back into the room and said "Why don't I hear music coming from this room?" and they complained "Why won't you let us play?", specifically using the word "play".  He said "I let you play all you want, go ahead, play" and the dark haired girl said something like "No, not the instruments, I mean play outside, like run around".  He kept insisting that they play more music for at least one hour.  They switched to arguing "at least let us play newer music".  One kid said "Yeah, that song is from the 50s or something, it's old fashioned."  "Let us play music we like."

And that's where I had to change the channel.

I feel like the father was a recognizable actor, but I don't recall who.  And I don't think any of the kids was a big-name actor.  I can't find any listings for VH1 for the past.  I tried googling things like "father forces three kids to be in pop band" without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to TVGuide.Com, VH1 was showing the movie [Selena](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120094/) last night from 8pm to 2am (back to back airings). The scene you mention is pretty early on in the movie. Edward James Olmos has the kids "play rock and roll," which to me sounds like he's trying to convince the kids it's a fun game to play on the instruments.

Comment: Yep. I googled the movie and even found reference in a review to the "Why don't I hear music?" line.  Thanks!